# Why is my spinner control blank when using resource strings?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using the following code to get a spinner working...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), andoird.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.spinner_items);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Everything compiles and runs happily. When the spinner is displayed, there's no text in it. When the spinner is touched, nothing seems to happen.  However, something has happened, because other controls lose focus and two touches are required to select a different item. When the app is touched the first time after touching the spinner, logcat says "*Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when using an array resource for spinner values, you have to do it slightly differently.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner_items, andoird.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Notice that instead of

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
```

You'll have to use

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
```

You'll also notice that the arguments are a bit different.

```
new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), andoird.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.spinner_items);

ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner_items, andoird.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

---

`public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

`public static ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createFromResource (Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId)`